# Connecting to Internet Problems

Tags: networking, netgear

So I came home from a week long vacation to find that my internet is no longer working. I do the usual (reset router, reset pc, check internet settings, etc.) and I noticed something strange.

Settings told me that I was perfectly connected, and it told me my IP, link speed, and it recognized the DNS from my router. However, when trying to open up Firefox and connect to Google.com, it says that it couldn't connect. I also tried Brave Browser and still just got the average "Couldn't connect" result.

I tried logging into my router, using 192.168.0.1 in Firefox and it works. I don't see anything out of the ordinary and even checked that my Network Settings on Ubuntu said the same info as the router, and sure enough it did.

I put "ping google.com" into my terminal and it spit out "ping: google.com: Name or service not known". I also tried "ping www.google.com" but to no different of a error.

I then went to bios and checked to see if anything was off, but to no avail. Please help me, I switched over to Ubuntu I would say a month ago or so and I am still learning a lot that I wouldn't have with Windows.

Also, Ethernet port on router/modem has a green light, while the port on my PC has a solid red and a blinking yellow. I don't know if that's normal or not, as I don't look back there often. I have also tried different ports on my PC and the modem/router, and that does nothing. Of course also tried a different cord that works with an XBox perfectly fine with the same modem/router. WiFi works perfectly okay as well on all devices. Time is also correct on PC, with Automatic Date and Time and Automatic Time Zone set to on in the Settings.

EDIT: When I go to ipchicken.com (on mobile) , it does show my external IP address. On another note, doing "ping 1.1.1.1" and "ping 8.8.8.8" in the Linux terminal, it can ping it, but the terminal says "ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted" (I tried with sudo but no change in result).

PC Info:
OS - Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS 64 bit
Motherboard - Gigabyte Aorus Z270X-Gaming K7 Motherboard
CPU - Intel i3-7350K 4.20GHz 4 Cores
RAM - 8GB
GPU - Radeon RX580 8GB
Storage - (boot drive) 120GB SSD, 2TB Hard Drive, 1TB External Hard Drive
Network - (one of those duel modem/router in one things) Netgear, with Ethernet. No WiFi adapter on PC.

(sorry for any spelling or grammar problems, im on mobile)

Comment: Suspect the issue is a router configuration but that is just a hunch; let's try to confirm that.  1) Are you able to ping 1.1.1.1 and 8.8.8.8? 2) Do you have another PC or smartphone which can connect through the router? 3) If so, can they connect to ipchicken.com and if so, does it show your external IP address? - Please click edit and add that useful information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment

Answer (score 0):

I posted this on Reddit and u/rsxhawk (https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/f6jmf1/connecting_to_internet_problems/fi5bpup?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share) commented a solution that worked for me.

The solution was to first go into Settings, click Network on the left side bar, then on your Ethernet, click the settings gear icon on the right, then click IPv4 on the upper tabs, then next to DNS there should be a "Automatic" switch, switch that off, then put "8.8.8.8" into the text box for DNS. Then reboot and that's what worked for me.

Hope this helps anyone struggling with this issue, and a huge thanks you to u/rsxhawk on the Ubuntu subreddit.